# Where would hierarchical tagging help us?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

In light of [this answer](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/273/5), I thought I might put together a list of where hierarchical tagging would help us, for example:

- [software](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)  can including things like [software-recommendations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations)
- [python](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) can include things like [pymatgen](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pymatgen)

Having this list will show SE how much use we'd have for such a feature, and also will help us do the actual tag adjustments easier when the time comes (if it does!).

Comment: Is there a tool to map the tags?

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of this would be reducing the need for broad, "field-specific" tags. Electronic-structure programs like [gaussian](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaussian), [qchem](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qchem), [molpro](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molpro), etc could all be classified under [electronic-structure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-structure) or [quantum-chemistry](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry). Molecular dynamics programs like [lammps](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lammps) or [gromacs](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gromacs) could be grouped under [molecular-dynamics](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-dynamics).

It would let questions have as specific of tags as possible, while still making them searchable under the most general terms. We currently generally discourage tags with only a few uses, but this wouldn't need to be the case with hierarchical tagging. For example, you could have a tag for any of the many [multiconfigurational](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/what-are-the-types-of-mcscf/1569#1569) or [quantum monte carlo](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/what-are-the-types-of-quantum-monte-carlo) methods and classify them all under a general parent tag.